# Typescript overloading type boolean is not assignable to type false

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a method that returns different type based on option key value.

```
class Test {
  getData(options: { obj: true }): Object;
  getData(options: { obj: false }): any[];
  getData(): any[];
  getData(options = { obj: false }): Object | any[] {
    if (options.obj) {
      return {};
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
}
```

When passing the `obj` as `true`, I'm returning object otherwise array. That works fine.

```
const instance = new Test();
const result = instance.getData({ obj: true }); // inffered as array
const result2 = instance.getData(); // inffered as object
```

The problem is when I need to use dynamic value it throws an error:

> type boolean is not assignable to type false

```
function getResult(obj: boolean = false ) {
  return instance.getData({ obj });
}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the type of `{ obj }` is only known as `{ obj: boolean }` at compile time, the compiler can't know to pick any of the overloads, you have to explicitly supply an overload that takes `{ obj: boolean }` (since the implementation signature does not count as a public signature for the function), the compiler will not do any magic in this case:

```
class Test {
    getData(options: { obj: true }): Object;
    getData(options: { obj: false }): any[];
    getData(options: { obj: boolean }): Object | any[];
    getData(): any[];
    // This signature is the implementation and is not conidered when resolving the method 
    getData(options = { obj: false }): Object | any[] {
        if (options.obj) {
            return {};
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

You can also use conditional types in the method signature and this will keep the number of signatures lower:

```
class Test {
    getData<T extends boolean>(options: { obj: T }): T extends true ? Object : any[];
    getData(): any[];
    // This signature is the implementation and is not conidered when resolving the method 
    getData(options = { obj: false }): Object | any[] {
        if (options.obj) {
            return {};
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    }
}


const instance = new Test();
const result = instance.getData({ obj: true }); // inffered as array
const result2 = instance.getData(); // inffered as object

function getResult(obj: boolean = false) {
    return instance.getData({ obj }); // inferred as Object|any[]
}
```

Since `type boolean = true | false` and conditional types distribute over unions, 
`T extends true ? Object : any[];` will be `Object|any[]` when `T` is `boolean`. When `T` is `true`, the return will be `Object` and when `T` is `false`, the return will be `any` all as expected

Comment: So I can't make typescript infer the return type of the dynamic function?

Comment: With the extra signature I added `getResult` would have the return type inferred correctly, but you need that extra signature on `getData`. The problem since the type is `Boolean` none of the signatiures match, and the compiler can't pick two signatures. There may be a conditional type approach, let me check ..

Comment: @undefined Added a conditional type approach as well, looks better to me, but you be the judge of that :)

Answer (score -3):

You cannot **overload** methods in TypeScript like you do in C#, for example. You need to combine types, like this:

```
class Test {

  getData(options: {obj: boolean} = { obj: false }): Object | any[]  {
   if (options.obj) {
        return {};
      } else {
        return [];
      }
   }
}
```

When you redeclare the function with the same name several times, you will just get the last one as the final definition, in runtime.

Comment: You CAN overload method signatures! You can't have multiple implementations

Comment: No, it really does not. It allows to declare methods without implementations, but it does not use it as type structure, making it just syntactic sugar. You have to declare the types inside the function that actually implements the body

Comment: Yes, and the question is specifically on how to use the syntactic sugar of multiple signatures. Your answer does not achieve the same type checking functionality, you just erase the signatures, they were there for a reason